# how to open a blank excel file with headers in asp.net using c#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel

i have a requirement to open a blank excel file on a click of button in front of the user with predefined headers. and user will fill the data's and upload that excel file then i will read that and update my database. My 1st concern is how to open that blank sheet in front of the user..

anyone pls help i really need this

Answer (score 0):

If your column headers are fixed then go with Excel Template. Create Excel template and open it with Process.Start("")

Comment: how? can u give me a small example ?

Comment: http://office.microsoft.com/en-in/excel-help/customizing-excel-defaults-with-templates-HA001054815.aspx

Comment: @Drone Which part are you not sure about? The template creation or the `Process.Start`?

Comment: template creation ... and is `Process.Start("")` is good way to do this?

Comment: and i couldn't find any thing from that link

Comment: @Drone, you want code??????????........... first read the link carefully and try your self. 

Above mentioned answer is just an suggestion for your question not an solution.

Comment: @Anandkumar ok i am able to create the blank excel sheet but i am getting it in my document as book1.xls can u tell me how i can get that in a particular folder and with a specified name?

Answer (score 0):

1. Create an excel file with the template of your choice
2. place the file inside a directory of your website.
3. Create link on a page to the file